# Cannot create new javascript object

Tags: javascript, object, charts, dojo

I am trying to use the `StoreSeries` with Dojo in order to create charts. However when I try to create the array by:

```
new StoreSeries(store, { query: { site: 1 } }, "value");
```

Then the javascript stops running and cannot continue to render the chart.

This is all the script that I think might be relevant - ask if you need to see any more.

```
function setupWeekElectricBar(Chart, theme, ClusteredColumns, Columns, Tooltip, Highlight, Observable, Memory, StoreSeries)
    {
    var data = [
        { id: 1, value: 5, site: 1 },
        { id: 2, value: 2, site: 1 },
        { id: 3, value: 3, site: 1 },
        { id: 4, value: 1, site: 1 },
        { id: 5, value: 3, site: 1 },
        { id: 6, value: 1, site: 1 }
    ];

    // Create the data store
    // Store information in a data store on the client side
    var store = Observable(new Memory({
        data: {
            identifier: "id",
            label: "Users Online",
            items: data
        }   
    }));

    var result = new StoreSeries(store, { query: { site: 1 } }, "value");

    //function does not get past here (checked using alert())

    }


require([       
         // Require the basic chart class
        "dojox/charting/Chart",

        // Require the theme of our choosing
        "dojox/charting/themes/Tufte",

        // Charting plugins: 

        //  We want to plot Pie and ClusteredColumns charts
        "dojox/charting/plot2d/Pie",
        "dojox/charting/plot2d/ClusteredColumns",
        "dojox/charting/plot2d/Columns",
        "dojox/charting/plot2d/Grid",


        // Retrieve the Legend, Tooltip, and MoveSlice classes
        "dojox/charting/action2d/Tooltip",
        "dojox/charting/action2d/MoveSlice",
         "dojox/charting/action2d/Highlight",

        //  We want to use Markers
        "dojox/charting/plot2d/Markers",

        //  We'll use default x/y axes
        "dojox/charting/axis2d/Default",

        "dojo/parser",

        "dojo/store/Observable",
        "dojo/store/Memory",
        "dojox/charting/StoreSeries",

        "dijit/dijit", // loads the optimized dijit layer
        "dijit/Calendar",


        // Wait until the DOM is ready
        "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(Chart, theme, Pie, ClusteredColumns, Columns, Grid, Tooltip, MoveSlice, Highlight, Observable, Memory, StoreSeries) {
        setupWeekElectricBar(Chart, theme, ClusteredColumns, Columns,Tooltip, Highlight, Observable, Memory, StoreSeries);
        }
});
```

Comment: What does your Javascript console say? If you can't find it, try wrapping `var result = new StoreSeries(store, { query: { site: 1 } }, "value");` in a `try/catch` block and `alert` out the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed by moving

```
"dojo/store/Observable",
"dojo/store/Memory",
"dojox/charting/StoreSeries",
```

further up.